# Different images the same height

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I have some images displayed in a grid. However they are different heights.

How would I get them to be the same size each?

Code so far.

p.s I'm using React hence `className`. It works exactly the same as `class`.

```
<ul className='grid gap-4 grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2 pb-10'>
  <li>
    <img
      className='min-h-full object-cover'
      height='800'
      width='800'
      loading='lazy'
      src={project.coverImage}
      alt={project.title}
    />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img
      className='min-h-full object-cover'
      height='800'
      width='800'
      loading='lazy'
      src={project.coverImage}
      alt={project.title}
    />
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Could you please a jsfiddle or sandbox for us to work with. Thanks.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your output?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the react syntax exactly but the height and width attributes in html needs to add px after the size number, but if there is no need for that in react so make sure there's not any styles overriding the height and width attributes.

If there's not you can add a class to the images and set through css the height as you want adding px after the number.

There is another attribute called object-fit with two values. The first one is cover which forces the image to cover the block and the second one is contain which makes the image fit inside the containing block.

This only works when you set the width and height of the container of the image, if you want a fixed width and height for all images with different sizes you could just set the height and width through css but that would make the images stretch so the best practice is to set fixed width and height for the image container and use object-fit contain for the image.